# Hibernate Annotate One-to-many on Primary Key

Tags: hibernate, annotations

Two tables here - one for cars, and one for stats on engines in cars. Engines are shared across cars, so there are multiple cars for every EngineStat.

I'd like to use hibernate to make a single query on EngineStat and receive all cars with that engine as a field of the EngineStat class.

I believe this is a one-to-many relationship, but do please correct me if that is wrong. I would like to use Java annotations only - no .hbm.xml file.

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "CAR", schema = "ftm")
class Car {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "car_id")
  long carId;

  @Column(name = "engine_id")
  long engineId;

  @Column(name = "model")
  ...... more stuff
}

@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "ENGINE_STAT", schema = "ftm")
class EngineStat {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "engine_id")
  long engineId;

  @Column(name = "horse_power")
  ..... more stuff

  // <---- Some annotations here 
  Set<Car> cars;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simpler than I expected (thought I tried this before posting, but I guess not).

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "CAR", schema = "ftm")
class Car {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "car_id")
  long carId;

  @Column(name = "engine_id")
  long engineId;

  @Column(name = "model")
  ...... more stuff
}

@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "ENGINE_STAT", schema = "ftm")
class EngineStat {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "engine_id")
  long engineId;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "engine_id")
  Set<Car> cars;

  @Column(name = "horse_power")
  ..... more stuff
}
```

Simply put engine ID in there as BOTH the primary key and your set. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to use `@OneToMany()`:

Adjust fetch type to suit and omit from `Car` if you wish.

In `EngineStat`:

```
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "car")
 public Set<Car> cars;
```

In `Car`

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "engine_id", nullable = false)
public EngineStat engineStat;
```

Edit:  To skip the modification to `Car`, do this in `EngineStat` instead:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "engine_id")
public Set<Car> cars;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without touching the `Car` class? This is part of a large shared project and the model for one table should not affect someone else's model.

Comment: @DavidZemon Yes; adjust the mapping inside `EngineStat` and omit the mapping from `Car`

Comment: With that, I now get an error informing me that my persistent entity should have a primary key.

I've updated the code in my original question with the class annotations being used

Comment: Turns out the error is an IntelliJ-specific inspection. But, when I run it, it fails with the hibernate exception: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.mycompany.EngineStat`

Comment: @DavidZemon  That last error message sounds like something is wrong with the `EngineStat` ID declaration

Comment: Yes, that's because `engine_id` is the ID. but i can't add the `@Id` annotation because it's a Set